# How to access "Automatically open XPS documents using the XPS viewer" option from code?

Tags: c#, vb.net, printing, xps

From the Microsoft XPS Document Writer Printing Preferences, there is an option to Automatically open a Viewer, that doesn't appear in the standard printer settings that I can find.
[Microsoft XPS Document Printing Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJkcz.jpg)

Is there a way to set or clear this option from a program (solution can be VB.net or C#)?

Comment: Supposedly you just need to change [this registry entry](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2e12f4fc-7f8b-4b64-813b-3acc3a532cc7/how-do-i-set-the-automatically-open-xps-documents-using-the-xps-viewer-for-xps-printers-for-a-large?forum=winserverprint).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Idle _Mind, and the registry path provided is good to know!  But I didn't want the program to require administrative rights for writing to the registry if I can help it.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, since no other answers are forthcoming so far, I've used the information that you provided to at least check the state of the option selection and then put up a message to the user to change it in cases where my program can't (not running in admin mode).  So, thanks again for your suggestion.  If you add it as an answer, I'll mark this as solved.